# Prove that sum of two non-symmetric matrices has strictly positive real parts for their eigen values.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory

Let $A = EJB + KL\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$, where $E=\operatorname{diag}(1,0,0,...,0)$, $J$ is the all-one matrix, $B,K$ are positive diagonal matrices and $L$ is the Laplacian matrix of a connected undirected graph, i.e. $L$ is a positive semi-definite matrix with zero row/column sums and $L$ is irreducible (so that $L$ is not permutationally similar to a block diagonal matrix with proper diagonal sub-blocks).

I can show that $A$ is non-singular.

However, how can we derive a (sufficient) condition on the parameters $E$ and $K$ such that all the eigenvalues of $A$ have positive real part?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: $EJ$ is just $J$, isn't it?

Comment: @TonyK No, the $E$ and $J$ are usually denoted as $e_1e_1^T$ and $ee^T$ in linear algebra literature, so that $EJ=e_1e^T$, the matrix with a row of ones on top of $n-1$ zero rows. The OP is basically asking for a proof that all eigenvalues of $A=e_1p^T + \operatorname{diag}(q)L$ have positive real parts when $p,q\in\mathbb R^n$ are two positive vectors and $L$ is an irreducible Laplacian matrix.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. Counterexample:
\begin{aligned}
A&=EJ\pmatrix{1\\ &1\\ &&120000\\ &&&120000}
+\pmatrix{1\\ &10000\\ &&100\\ &&&100}\pmatrix{3&-1&-1&-1\\ -1&3&-1&-1\\ -1&-1&3&-1\\ -1&-1&-1&3}\\
&=\pmatrix{1&1&120000&120000\\ 0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0}
+\pmatrix{3&-1&-1&-1\\ -10000&30000&-10000&-10000\\ -100&-100&300&-100\\ -100&-100&-100&300}\\
&=\pmatrix{4&0&119999&119999\\ -10000&30000&-10000&-10000\\ -100&-100&300&-100\\ -100&-100&-100&300}.
\end{aligned}
According to both Octave and [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eigenvalues+%7B%7B4,0,119999,119999%7D,%7B-10000,30000,-10000,-10000%7D,%7B-100,-100,300,-100%7D,%7B-100,-100,-100,300%7D%7D), $A$ has a conjugate pair of eigenvalues $-58.3941\pm5626.57i$ with negative real parts.